# Symbolism in illustration for a book by Riccati

Tags: biographical-details, mathematicians

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacopo_Riccati) has a jpeg of the front cover of the book Opere (1761) by Jacopo Riccati, author of the celebrated Riccati equation. What is the symbolism incorporated in this illustration?

[image]

See discussion of the possible symbolism and a higher resolution image at the cross-posted question at History SE https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34977/symbolism-in-illustration-for-a-book-by-riccati.

Comment: Pretty much everything can be explained in the illustration now except the two pages of mathematical drawings and the quiver-like container (for scrolls?).